# Query update last record only and value from other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

oc_stock_hpp

```
id product_id stock
2  1234       0
3  5678       0
4  1234       0
6  1234       0
9  5678       0
```

oc_product

```
id product_id quantity
1  1234       7
23 5678       9
```

My purpose is to update value in the stock field table oc_stock_hpp where id=6 become 7 and id=9 become 9 as in oc_product table

I have tried

```
UPDATE oc_stock_hpp t1 
    INNER JOIN oc_product t2 
         ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
SET t1.stock = t2.quantity
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM oc_stock_hpp GROUP BY product_id)
```

and got error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: `GROUP BY product_id` it means returns max values for each  `product_id` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have as result only 1 id

> ```
> CREATE TABLE oc_stock_hpp (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `product_id` INTEGER,
>   `stock` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO oc_stock_hpp
>   (`id`, `product_id`, `stock`)
> VALUES
>   ('2', '1234', '0'),
>   ('3', '5678', '0'),
>   ('4', '1234', '0'),
>   ('6', '1234', '0'),
>   ('9', '5678', '0');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE oc_product (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `product_id` INTEGER,
>   `quantity` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO oc_product
>   (`id`, `product_id`, `quantity`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1234', '7'),
>   ('23', '5678', '9');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE oc_stock_hpp t1 
>     INNER JOIN oc_product t2 
>          ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
> SET t1.stock = t2.quantity
> WHERE t1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM (SELECT * FROM oc_stock_hpp) o1 WHERE product_id = t2.product_id)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM oc_stock_hpp
> ```
>
> ```
> id | product_id | stock
> -: | ---------: | ----:
>  2 |       1234 |     0
>  3 |       5678 |     0
>  4 |       1234 |     0
>  6 |       1234 |     7
>  9 |       5678 |     9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=907ff999ab73d417741b8ff5c59a7b45)*

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE oc_stock_hpp t1                        -- this table copy will be updated
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) id, product_id          -- this subquery allows to define
       FROM oc_stock_hpp t2                   -- the most last row ( and this row
       GROUP BY 2 ) t3 USING (id, product_id) -- will be updated only )
JOIN oc_product t4 USING (product_id)         -- this table copy provides new value
SET t1.stock = t4.quantity;                   -- and perform the update
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54b5b671ada99ec44ae24a5353460320

Answer (score 1):

You must make the subquery return one and only one result:

```
UPDATE oc_stock_hpp t1 
    INNER JOIN oc_product t2 
         ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
SET t1.stock = t2.quantity
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM oc_stock_hpp GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY t1.id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This is the easiest way for me.

Comment: Causes **Error 1093** "You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1182877d78658c6b1a3869a9b466c053

Comment: The question does not specify the database engine used or the version, so my answer was tested in **MariaDB** (which is what I have installed locally) and it works perfectly. In the same [link]https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=7424f79307d06c7acb581e58cdcbf4e2 you can try it

Comment: *The question does not specify the database engine used* I see that the question is tagged: [mysql].